# How to put a display a default image if no src specified?

Tags: jquery

I have HTML from a database that sometimes give no src values like this:

```
<img class="some-image" src="">
```

How do I supply it with an image if there is no src value like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test the src attribute to see if it's empty:

```
$('img[src=""]').attr("src", "default.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src=""]').attr('src', 'urltoimage');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it on the css class as background for the  tag and overwrite it with the src tag where available. Are you meaning this?